# UISearchBar Scope Bar Not Showing

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have a UIScopeBar as a subview of a UIVIew as a peer of a UITableView.  When I attempt to show the scope bar, it appears behind the first row of the table view. If I attempt to shift the tableview down programatically when editing of the searchbar begins, a second unfiltered tableview appears, and still covers the scopebar.  How do I bring the scopebar to the "front"?

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue, but my UISearchBar is part from the navigation bar with this option displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar. I try to add the scope bar from interface builder, from code, from initialization, from too many places but I can't show it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to do something out of the ordinary, I think you would be better served by using a `UITableviewController` (instead of a UIViewController) and a `UISearchDisplayController` (instead of a UISSearchBar/UIScopeBar). You can do this in the Storyboard by dragging the TableView Controller onto the storyboard and then dragging out a "Search Bar and SearchDisplay Controller" and placing it above the provided TableView, (or, if you have a NavBar, between the TableView and the NavBar) - it should lock into place automatically.

`UISearchDisplayController` will automatically take care of the search results table display and you can set it to show the ScopeBar when the searchBar editing begins either using the storyboard as you've done, or programmatically using something like:

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
```

Otherwise, if you want to stick with what you've described, then if I've understood your setup you have a UIViewController into which you've added two subviews, a UISearchBar with ScopeBar and a UITableView.

It's a bit hard to tell exactly what you want to do without seeing your code, but if you drag your SearchBar *into* your tableview, then it will attach itself as your tableViews tableHeaderView, which will then show the SearchBar with ScopeBars at the top of the tableview, which I think is what you want.

Hope that helps!